# Simplifying a modulo expression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a,x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ with $ax \ge y$, and let % be the remainder from integer divison, always positive. Define $$A:=y \text{%} a + (a x -y) \text{%} a.$$Then using the distributive property for %, it is true that $A$%$a=0$. From this we infer that there exists an $n : \mathbb{N}^3 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $$A = a n(x, y).$$

It is clear that $n(x, y) = \frac{y \text{%} a + (a x -y) \text{%}a}{a}.$ How can I simplify the form of $n$ to express it without the division by $a$?

Comment: Surely $A=0$ and $n=0$?

Comment: Hint: show that $n(x,y,a)=0$ if $y\mid a$ and $n(x,y,a)=1$ if $y\nmid a$. (Did you try numerical examples? This conjecture should be fairly easy to formulate.)

Comment: Does the $\%$-operator give negative for negative, or is the result always in the range $[0, a-1]$?

Comment: @GregMartin so you're suggesting that $n = \mathbb{1}(y \dnd a)$? The $y|a$ case is clear, but I'm not sure what to do when $y\dnd a$

Comment: @ploosu2 I edited to cover your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \mid y$, then clearly $n(x,y,a) = 0$.

And if $a\nmid y$, then already $y \% a > 0$, so $A$ being the sum of this positive term and something else non-negative is positive and we have to have $n(x,y,a)>0$. Since $A<2a$, we have $n(x,y,a)=1$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I used $(-x)\%a<0$, would that mean that $n=0$ identically?

Comment: @Joe Well for these numbers with $ax \geq y$ the outcome wouldn't change, would it. So you still have these cases. But for $ax<y$ yes I believe you would get $n=0$ identically.

Comment: Well, with even with $ax>y$ then I can write $A= y\%a + (-y)\%a$, and then I'm wondering if some programming languages define $(-x)\%a := -(x\%a)$, which would give $A=0$? It seems counterintuitive to me to have $x\%a <0$

Comment: If ever $(-x)\%a$ is defined to be $-(x\%a)$, then it is no longer always true that $(ax-y)\%a = (-y)\%a$. (Which is one of many reasons that $(-x)\%a := -(x\%a)$ is a terrible definition.) Simple experiments with $x=0$, then $x=1$, ... will demonstrate that there's no nice formula for the sum in the OP under this alternate convention.

Comment: @GregMartin yes I was thinking this after I made that comment. What is the consistent definition that allows for $y\%a<0$ when $y<0$?

Comment: There is no such consistent definition, in my experience.